# Python 3.12 pip install mod_wsgi fails

Tags: python, django, apache, deployment, debian

I am trying to deploy Django rest framework on my Debian 10 server.
I am using Apache2 but he keeps crashing because its not using the right python version.

I am using python3.12 version for my project :

```
python --version
Python 3.12.2
```

But Apache2 is running with python3.7 so its crashing because it cant find Django Module

```
Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) mod_wsgi/4.6.5 Python/3.7 configured
```

I tried to install mod_wsgi with pip but I keep getting this error :

```
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: nonrepresentable section on output
      collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mod_wsgi
Failed to build mod_wsgi
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mod_wsgi, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Thanks to everyone fo your time !

I tried everything I found on existing topics.

I am expecting a solution to be able to install mod_wsgi and use the right python version on my apache2 server